# Kafka gives Invalid receive size with Hyperledger Fabric Orderer connection

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

I was setting up a new cluster for Hyperledger Fabric on EKS. The cluster has 4 kafka nodes, 3 zookeeper nodes, 4 peers, 3 orderers, 1 CA. All the containers come up individually, and the kafka/zookeeper backend is also stable. I can SSH into any kafka/zookeeper and check for connections to any other nodes, create topics, post messages etc. The kafka is accessible via Telnet from all orderers.

When I try to create a channel I get the following error from the orderer:

```
2019-04-25 13:34:17.660 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 025 [channel: channel1] Rejecting broadcast of message from 192.168.94.15:53598 with SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: rejected by Consenter: backing Kafka cluster has not completed booting; try again later
2019-04-25 13:34:17.660 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 026 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=192.168.94.15:53598 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=14.805833ms
2019-04-25 13:34:17.661 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 027 Error reading from 192.168.94.15:53596: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-04-25 13:34:17.661 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 028 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.94.15:53596 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=24.987468ms
```

And the Kafka leader reports the following error:

```
[2019-04-25 14:07:09,453] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=2] Unexpected error from /192.168.89.200; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 369295617 larger than 104857600)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:231)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:528)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:469)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:398)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:535)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:452)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-04-25 14:13:53,917] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=2] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that you are receiving messages larger than the permitted maximum size, that defaults to ~100MB. Try to increase the following property in `server.properties` file, so that it can fit larger receive (in this case at least 369295617 bytes):

```
# Set to 500MB
socket.request.max.bytes=500000000
```

and then restart your Kafka Cluster.

If this doesn't work for you, then I guess that you are trying to connect to a non-SSL listener. Therefore, you'd have to verify that broker's SSL listener port is `9092` (or the corresponding port in case you are not using the default one) . The following should do the trick:

```
listeners=SSL://:9092
advertised.listeners=SSL://:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=SSL
```